# Handlebars js, get specific object array and loop through

Tags: json, if-statement, handlebars.js

I'm trying to generat two tables from an array.

```
"tables": [
{
"tableName": "table1",
"dataRow": ["name": "test858"]
},
{
"tableName": "table2",
"anotherRow": ["name": "test123"]
}
]
```

i tried doing this

```
{{#each tables}}
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{tableName}}</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {{#if dataRow}}
                        <td>test1</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td>test2</td>
                        {{/if}}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
 {{/each}}
```

this prints the two tablenames and "test2"

How can I loop through both arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mblenton/s0oguLxw/2/):

```
var entry_template = document.getElementById('entry-template').innerHTML;
var tables = [
{
"tableName": "table1",
"dataRow": [{"name": "test858"}]
},
{
"tableName": "table2",
"anotherRow": [{"name": "test123"}]
}
];

var template = Handlebars.compile(entry_template);
var template_with_data = template(tables);

document.getElementById('data').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', template_with_data);
```

Template:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each this}}
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{tableName}}</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {{#if dataRow}}
                        <td>test1</td>
                        {{else}}
                        <td>test2</td>
                        {{/if}}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
 {{/each}}  
</script>
<div id="data">
</div>
```